# Add embedded recipient without email?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an embedded recipient and set the clientUserId so that it won't send an email. However, I know if I don't include an email I get

```
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows."
}
```

But because the recipients sign on my application they do not need to have an email. Is there a way to make it not needed when creating an envelope outside from my workaround of sending it a dummy email address?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that currently.
There are plans to enable support for SMS as an identifier, so you could use a phone number, but that is potentially in the future.
The reason an email is needed is not because emails has to be sent to that address, but as part of some unique way to identify the person. Just adding "Joe smith" as a signer, doesn't tell DocuSign who is that Joe Smith. You could use the same email that you used for the account (yours maybe) and just have a different name, which would be a strange thing to do, but it is allowed. DocuSign does support multiple people using the same email address, it's not recommended, but the uniqueness of the signer is created by combining their name and their email address together.